# How to config Netlify CMS to store blogs under a different folder rather than directly under project root

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

[image]

I am using Netlify + Netlify CMS + Gatsby to do my Blog.

I start seeing more and more reduxcacheXXXXX folders appearing in project root folder.

If I don't need them, how could I remove them and prevent these folder from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are cached files that appear since Gatsby 2.19. It seems that they have permission issues when trying to remove (and rename) them in each build as shows this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22562)

Here you can find detailed documentation about [data storage with Redux in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-storage-redux/) and how it is used:

> During Gatsby’s bootstrap & build phases, the state is stored and
>   manipulated using the Redux library. The key purpose of using Redux in
>   Gatsby internals is to centralize all of the state logic. Reviewing
>   the Gatsby reducers and actions folders gives a comprehensive picture
>   of what state manipulations are possible.

To clarify is not an issue of using Netlify. It happens with all CMS (I have a Contentful and DatoCMS own projects and still happening).

Answering your question, it seems the "bug" persists. You should ignore those files and remove them as soon as you see it. In addition, you can try to update your Gatsby packages to the latest stable version.

Comment: great~! so the reduxcacheXXX folders are not necessary for repo, it's generated by Gatsby.js and they have nothing to do with Netlify(CMS), neither for blog posts.

Comment: Exactly, that's it. I don't know if it has something to do with it but they only appear in my projects when I have network issues. Anyway, updating your packages may solve the issue. I can't confirm if it's fixed in the latest versions it but I haven't seen them in a long time in my projects.